# Show that $F(x) = \int_{-\infty ,x}f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, continuity

Let $f \in L^1(m)$ where $m$ is the standard Lebesgue measure. Show that $$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x}f \text{ is continuous on } \mathbb{R}.$$

I think what is confusing me is that my professor labeled it as $F(x) = \int_{-\infty,x} f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. My plan for this was to try and use the Dominated Convergence Theorem as an attempt to answer this proof.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Dominated Convergence may help.  Hint:
If $x_n \to x$, consider the sequence $\chi_n f$ where $\chi_n$ is the indicator function of the interval $[x_n, x]$ or $[x,x_n]$.

Comment: Don't you mean $\chi_n$ to be the indicator function of $(-\infty, x_n]$?

Comment: Never mind - both obviously work.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on that by using the sequence?

Comment: $\left| \int_{-\infty}^x f - \int_{-\infty}^{x_n} f\right| = \left|\int \chi_n f \right|$.  Use Dominated Convergence to show this goes to $0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks on that! That's exactly what I needed in this case